# rnoaa station data pull times out

Tags: r, curl, timeout, rnoaa

I'm trying to pull NOAA data using R. I've done this pull before but all of a sudden it's not working. I have rnoaa loaded (package/library) and I have an authorization key from the NOAA. I try to run this command:

```
station_data <- ghcnd_stations()
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(x$url$url, handle = x$url$handle) : Timeout was reached: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I found pages online that suggested updating everything. First I updated all my packages and then updated to a new version of R. All that done, it's still giving me a timeout message with this simple command. I know that the ghcnd pull sometimes take a while, but it's timing out after about 10 seconds. Is this just an noaa issue (as is sometimes the case) and I should try again tomorrow? Or is there something I can actually do to make this work? Can I change the timeout period so that it waits longer? Is the NOAA just overloaded because of the hurricane?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just something on the NOAA end of things. It took a day, but it's finally back up and running properly.

Comment: `rnoaa` maintainer here. glad its working now. yeah, NOAA sites are not super reliable. and can be completely down during government shutdowns too.